# MKDIR and CHMOD working , upload doesn't succeed

Tags: php, mysql, permissions, webserver

I have a really simple PHP script that creates a directory according to a product id, these folders are made to upload product id specific images into it.

Once this folder is made with PHP script `mkdir('folder',0777)` I upload an image with PHP to that just made folder. This doesn't work as it should : the `move_uploaded_file` function returns a regulation in the server `safe_mode` function. Although this the servers `safe_mode`property is turned off, is still gives this error / warning.

When I check with my FTP user account, I see the made directory with permission 777, but the uploads won't succees to upload to that directory...

Strangeness of it is that when i manually delete the made directory and make a new one (via FTP) the uploads work perfect!

Does anyone have any clue on fixing this issue? I'm not that server experienced :)
Thanks!

Comment: Show the exact error message and the exact path(s) you are working with. PHP's safe mode restrictions are independent from FTP

Comment: This is probably a "base restriction" which is sometimes misnamed as "safe mode". Check that there are no base restrictions in effect.

Comment: But if the safe mode is on, uploading an image with a PHP script wouldn't also be possible no? The error message : Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid is 10109 is not allowed to access /var/www/vhosts/upsn.be/httpdocs/admin/products/18 owned by uid 502 in /var/www/vhosts/upsn.be/httpdocs/admin/logic/addfoto.php on line 19

Answer (score 0):

use this for mkdir username is your foldername in uplod folder

```
 if(!is_dir('uploads/'.$username . "/")) {
 mkdir('uploads/'.$username . "/", 0755);
 }`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to take in account, that when creating a directory the create mask is anded with the [umask](http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php):

```
$old = umask( 0 );
mkdir( 'folder', 0777, true );
umask( $old );
```

Answer (score 0):

The mode on your directory may be being affected by your current umask.  It will end
up having `(mkdir-mode & (~umask))` permissions.

Try:

```
$oldmask = umask(0);
mkdir('folder', 0777);
umask($oldmask);
```